# Run VBS script from different security contexts

Tags: java, windows, cmd, vbscript, outlook

I want to automate the creation of a new email from my java Application. For this I am generating a VBS script which will collect all the information (Email Content, Subject, Attachments, etc ) and it will generate the VBS script that will open a new email view from outlook with all the fields correctly field.(I don't want to automatically send the email, Just want to create a new mail in the outlook client.) Below you can see how I run the script from the java APP:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + nameOfScript);
```

All the time my Java App is ran with Admin Privileges.
When the User has the Outlook App application open with Admin Privileges, everything works fine.
When the User has the Outlook App application open without Admin Privileges, the script will not work any more. It will fail on the following line:

```
Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```

Error code is 429 -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications

It seems that because I am running the script with Admin Privileges the GetObject function will always fail if outlook is running without admin Privileges.

Is there a workaround for this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use runas service from windows, and your command will become like this

```
String command = "runas /user:"+domain+"/"+user+" \"wscript C:\\Path\\to\\your\\script.vbs\"";
```

The bad part is that runas command requires user's password, and the worst part is that you cannot provide it via process from Java. **It must be input from keyboard.**

This will NOT work:

```
       while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
       {
           System.out.println(line);
           if(line.toLowerCase().matches(".*enter.*password.*"))
           {
               System.out.println("Writing password for the user");
               os.write(password);
               os.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
               os.close();
           }
       }
```

What you could do is:

- write a .bat file with runas command above execute it and let the
- user insert his password into cmd window

Comment: Thanks for looking over this. Even though for my project it is not accepted to have the user type in a password in the cmd window, your answer made me better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment and the error message, it is difficult to point out the reason that cause the problem. I would like to provide some suggestions as the as follows:

1. The object is available on the machine, but it is a licensed Automation object, and can't verify the availability of the license necessary to instantiate it.

   Some objects can be instantiated only after the component finds a license key, which verifies that the object is registered for instantiation on the current machine. When a reference is made to an object through a properly installed type library or object library, the correct key is supplied automatically.

   If the attempt to instantiate is the result of a CreateObject or GetObject call, the object must find the key. In this case, it may search the system registry or look for a special file that it creates when it is installed, for example, one with the extension .lic. If the key can't be found, the object can't be instantiated. If an end user has improperly set up the object's application, inadvertently deleted a necessary file, or changed the system registry, the object may not be able to find its key. If the key can't be found, the object can't be instantiated. In this case, the instantiation may work on the developer's system, but not on the user's system. It may be necessary for the user to reinstall the licensed object.
2. You are trying to use the GetObject function to retrieve a reference to class created with Visual Basic. 
   GetObject can't be used to obtain a reference to a class created with Visual Basic.
3. Access to the object has explicitly been denied. For example, you may be trying to access a data object that's currently being used and is locked to prevent deadlock situations. If that's the case, you may be able to access the object at another time.

For more information, please refer to these links:

[Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0653f685-4526-45d9-89f3-8c479a6b4c62/runtime-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object?forum=vblanguage)

[Run-Time error 429 when using GetObject (,"Outlook.Application")](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ad9be960-9cca-40ab-9efb-1e7ac9d5d1a2/runtime-error-429-when-using-getobject-quotoutlookapplicationquot?forum=accessdev)

Comment: I don't think that is the problem since it works fine if the OP started Outlook as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for having a look over my issue. I don't think that I am missing an ActiveX component since the implementation is working fine when the Outlook is ran with admin and also the Script is ran with Admin. The issue described above appears only when  Outlook is ran without admin and VBS script is ran with admin.

Comment: @RaduSR I updated my answer, Hope it will help for you.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer. Before writing this post, I've made my own analysis and I've already covered all the links from above. It could be an answer for someone else that has a similar issue with the same error code.